# Keyword used in Select From SQL Statement (C# OleDbDataAdapter)

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, oledbdataadapter

I am attempting to read the tables of a database into a dataset.  I have a table named "CASE" which causes an error: "Syntax Error in From Clause".  Upon further inspection, it would seem that "CASE" is an SQL/Access Keyword.  Is there an "Escape Sequence" of sorts that would ignore this (i.e. The "\" in C# strings, or will I have to rename the table?

I have attempted to surround the table name in parenthesis, which didn't work, as well as surrounding the table name in quotes, which threw another error.

Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, is this an Access table or is it in SQL Server?

Comment: This is an Access Database.

Comment: typically you would surround the table name with square brackets, e.g. `[CASE]`

Comment: @BrianDriscoll I was just typing that as an answer. Since you wrote it up first, I'll defer to you.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, square brackets `[KeywordTableName]`